# Kong: kong-spec-expose plugin cannot load the documentation(302 permanently moved)

Tags: swagger, kong, kong-plugin

I have hard times configuring this kong-spec-expose plugin.It is supposed to automatically configure the routes with Swagger. After some time I managed to configure it but when i try to access the documentation of a certain route it is always giving me the 302 permanently moved.So i tested it with curl and here I will leave a link for the kong plugin and a screenshot of the request..

https://docs.konghq.com/hub/optum/kong-spec-expose/

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8000...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8000 (#0)
> GET /api/employee-controller/profile/user/12/base/specz HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8000
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
< Date: Wed, 11 Jan 2023 09:50:38 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Kong-Response-Latency: 409
< Server: kong/2.8.1
```

Actually I tried configuring the plugin on multiple routes then on service level but nothing seems to work out.. then tried to analyse where this request is redirected but with no results.

Comment: Could you paste the configuration and tests you've tried (confidential info censored, of course)? I don't know if requesting `/specz/` and  `/specz/` work the same way. Also, can you ensure that kong can reach the OAS URL and that the requested method is GET?

Comment: ops i was applying a wrong logs now its the correct one with the line 302 Moved Temporarily.The configurations steps are the following. Firstly I added the plugin in the kong.conf.default and uncomented the line,then renamed the file to kong.conf otherwise it was saying the plugin is not enabled.Actually I now realized that the config.spec_url field in the kong docs is just a pointer to this url ```https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/examples/v2.0/json/petstore.json``` that is essentially some random configuration and maybe it is needed to make my own configuration to work..

Comment: So the curl result is 302. Can you make sure that curl follows the redirect made by the plugin (maybe adding `-L` to curl command). The plugin just send GET request to the URL, so maybe pointing at raw GitHub content might help (something like `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/main/examples/v2.0/json/petstore.json`)

Comment: yep i make the curl request with -L but now interestingly when i added this url as u pointed out it always opens up the raw page with pets info...       ```"paths": {
    "/pets": {
      "get": {
        "summary": "List all pets",
        "operationId": "listPets",
        "tags": [
          "pets"
```

Comment: Did the return value the same as opening the link directly with a browser? If so I think the plugin is working as intended, showing OAS for the consumer.

Comment: thank u very much,sir! Appreciated